# Where condition on laravel model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models. i.e, `Posts` and `Tags`.

**Post Model**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'tbl_post_tags', 'in_post_id', 'in_tag_id');
}
```

**Tag Model**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Post', 'tbl_post_tags', 'in_tag_id', 'in_post_id');
}
```

I want to fetch those posts which have `php` tag.

This is what I have done till now.

**Search Controller**

```
Post::with(['tags'])->skip(0)->take(5)->get();
```

I'm getting first five posts from table. But there is a post in these list which doesn't have `PHP` tag. So as per my requirement, I must get next post from table which have `PHP` tag.

I can't find any document on official site of laravel. If anyone knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you search the tags by name, here is the code.

```
Post::with(['tags'])->whereHas('tags', function($query){
    $query->where("name", 'PHP');
})->skip(0)->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: I'm getting `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, none given` error as per your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Post::whereHas(['tags' => function($q) use($name){
  $q->where('name', $name); // $name = 'PHP'
}])->take(5)->get();
```